# WPF Application - Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to create a desktop application for windows using Xamarin Visual Studio but i cannot find WPF application. I saw in other S.O questions that Visual Studio does support.

Do i have to install any plugin?

Comment: Are you looking to create a wpf app or use xamarin forms with wpf?

Comment: @KenTucker, WPF application for a windows desktop

Comment: Xamarin is for cross-platform mobile/UWP/Mac development, not WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Visual Studio 2017 installer and select modify.   Make sure the windows workflow is selected and press continue.  This will add support for WPF and windows forms apps

WPF is not supported in Visual Studio for Mac

Comment: Visual studio for mac does not support wpf projects.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is not cross-platform, it is Windows desktop only. And there is no "plugin" that changes this.

So if you want to create a WPF desktop application you should use Visual Studio on Windows and nothing else.